# Magento 2 : How To Customize Validation Error Message

Tags: magento2, custom, form-validation

Is there a way to add a custom error message to a [custom validator](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html)?

I use already the default rule `required-entry`, can I define my own rules? and where exactly?

I found something with [overwriting](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10474) the `validation.js`, but I find this too cucumbersome. Isn't there a simpler way to do that?

LE:

Just to add more insight into the question:
the validation works, but when I get an error (from my logic) the field doesn't show any message (when no values in the input field are given then appears the `required field` text - but this is the default rule).

Meanwhile, I've tried [this](http://www.webmull.com/magento-2-add-new-custom-form-validation/), but somehow the javascript part doesn't respond at all.